# How to search for the video id by name in nested JSON Response?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, google-colaboratory

This is my JSON response API, I want to search for the video id by name. I mean Get VideoID using Video Name.
**For example:** I want to input 'film10' and Python returns '82da4b60ef' as a result. I am using API Response JSON; this is the JSON:

```
{
   'results': [{
           'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'id': '6ed909bd16',
           'partition': None,
           'externalId': None,
           'metadata': None,
           'name': 'NewSeptemberFile20220908',
           'description': None,
           'created': '2022-09-12T22:04:55.799+00:00',
           'lastModified': '2022-09-12T22:06:10.838+00:00',
           'lastIndexed': '2022-09-12T22:05:04.551+00:00',
           'privacyMode': 'Private',
           'userName': 'M M',
           'isOwned': True,
           'isBase': True,
           'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
           'state': 'Processed',
           'moderationState': 'OK',
           'reviewState': 'None',
           'processingProgress': '100%',
           'durationInSeconds': 58,
           'thumbnailVideoId': '6ed909bd16',
           'thumbnailId': '5f04af4d-e382-4387-9573-6d9e4bad3b68',
           'searchMatches': [],
           'indexingPreset': 'Default',
           'streamingPreset': 'Default',
           'sourceLanguage': 'en-GB',
           'sourceLanguages': ['en-GB'],
           'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       }, {
           'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'id': '34344818e8',
           'partition': None,
           'externalId': None,
           'metadata': None,
           'name': '3September',
           'description': None,
           'created': '2022-09-09T17:55:59.696+00:00',
           'lastModified': '2022-09-09T17:57:51.057+00:00',
           'lastIndexed': '2022-09-09T17:56:04.544+00:00',
           'privacyMode': 'Private',
           'userName': 'M M',
           'isOwned': True,
           'isBase': True,
           'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
           'state': 'Processed',
           'moderationState': 'OK',
           'reviewState': 'None',
           'processingProgress': '100%',
           'durationInSeconds': 58,
           'thumbnailVideoId': '34344818e8',
           'thumbnailId': 'baae7ed1-a791-4481-853c-1707b40b5e77',
           'searchMatches': [],
           'indexingPreset': 'Default',
           'streamingPreset': 'Default',
           'sourceLanguage': 'en-GB',
           'sourceLanguages': ['en-GB'],
           'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       }, {
           'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'id': '82da4b60ef',
           'partition': None,
           'externalId': None,
           'metadata': None,
           'name': 'film10',
           'description': None,
           'created': '2022-08-22T14:24:08.442+00:00',
           'lastModified': '2022-09-08T23:13:16.416+00:00',
           'lastIndexed': '2022-08-22T14:24:12.605+00:00',
           'privacyMode': 'Private',
           'userName': 'M M',
           'isOwned': True,
           'isBase': True,
           'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
           'state': 'Processed',
           'moderationState': 'OK',
           'reviewState': 'None',
           'processingProgress': '100%',
           'durationInSeconds': 58,
           'thumbnailVideoId': '82da4b60ef',
           'thumbnailId': '5a5f6a71-0302-46a6-93c8-beb918c00b14',
           'searchMatches': [],
           'indexingPreset': 'Default',
           'streamingPreset': 'Default',
           'sourceLanguage': 'en-GB',
           'sourceLanguages': ['en-GB'],
           'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       }, {
           'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'id': '7ea0c5e34a',
           'partition': None,
           'externalId': None,
           'metadata': None,
           'name': 'davide_quatela--people_in_frankfurt',
           'description': None,
           'created': '2022-09-07T21:31:52.818+00:00',
           'lastModified': '2022-09-08T22:52:52.833+00:00',
           'lastIndexed': '2022-09-07T21:31:57.328+00:00',
           'privacyMode': 'Private',
           'userName': 'M M',
           'isOwned': True,
           'isBase': True,
           'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
           'state': 'Processed',
           'moderationState': 'OK',
           'reviewState': 'None',
           'processingProgress': '100%',
           'durationInSeconds': 131,
           'thumbnailVideoId': '7ea0c5e34a',
           'thumbnailId': '3aba8f42-a3a7-4d77-92b0-8cabcc275a3b',
           'searchMatches': [],
           'indexingPreset': 'Default',
           'streamingPreset': 'Default',
           'sourceLanguage': 'en-US',
           'sourceLanguages': ['en-US'],
           'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       }, {
           'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           'id': '7c45ae7ffe',
           'partition': None,
           'externalId': None,
           'metadata': None,
           'name': 'Untitled project',
           'description': None,
           'created': '2022-08-17T17:36:23.72+00:00',
           'lastModified': '2022-08-17T17:36:49.95+00:00',
           'lastIndexed': '2022-08-17T17:36:49.95+00:00',
           'privacyMode': 'Private',
           'userName': 'M M',
           'isOwned': True,
           'isBase': False,
           'hasSourceVideoFile': False,
           'state': 'Processed',
           'moderationState': 'OK',
           'reviewState': 'None',
           'processingProgress': '',
           'durationInSeconds': 0,
           'thumbnailVideoId': None,
           'thumbnailId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
           'searchMatches': [],
           'indexingPreset': None,
           'streamingPreset': 'Default',
           'sourceLanguage': 'en-US',
           'sourceLanguages': ['en-US'],
           'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       }
   ],
   'nextPage': {
       'pageSize': 25,
       'skip': 0,
       'done': True
   } 
}
```

This is my code, I get the API data by the requests get method and it returns '200' that it does mean the code is working properly.

```
url = "https://api.video.ai/trial/Accounts//Videos/7ea0c5e34a/Index?language=af-ZA&reTranslate=false&includeStreamingUrls=true&includeSummarizedInsights=true&accessToken="

    response = requests.get(url,headers=hdr )
    ### Response: 200 OK
    print("If Response=200 Script run is OK : " , response.status_code)
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this so far? Add that to your code please

Answer (score 0):

So the url does not open on my end. cannot fetch the json.

using the json provided by you -

```py
for item in json_data['results']:
    if item['name'] == 'film10':
        print(item['id'])
```

gives

```
82da4b60ef
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
for result in response['results']:
    if result['name'] == ('YOUR FILM NAME INPUT'):
        return result['id']
```

As you can see the response has a list with the results called "results", so this code runs through it and check if the name equals the name you want to check.